# How to open specified directory

Tags: android, directory

I have application which generate PDF, then I put in folder A, how can I open and exploring all files in folder A when clicked button (showing new Intent)? I wish that my preview like when click My Files >> Folder A >> [files].

Comment: where is folder ? sdcard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doe this code help?
[original source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17166420/2636887)

```
String folderPath = Environnement.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/A";

Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri myUri = URI.parse(folderPath);
intent.setType("file/*");   
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I got error when do this android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT

Comment: replace intent.setDataAndType(myUri , "file/*"); with intent.setType("file/*");

Comment: it is working now, my fault is setType with Uri as parameter, thank you.

Comment: is it possible also, when I choose one of them, then open my pdf file? I cannot open my pdf file directly

Comment: Sorry i don't completely understand your question,anyway You can write an onActivityResult() function and instead of starting with just startActivity() call startActivityForResult()

Comment: for your code, it is working now, it can show list of directory, but when I choose my folder, then get my pdf files, I cannot open it, is it possible to open?

Comment: Yes you can that is what i said in the last comment,you can get the file Uri in the onActivityResult() and write code to read from a pdf file in that function,try to google onActivityResult()

Comment: hello, i just follow your ways, and it is working, how can I get pdf file name when I choose it from the list? actually if I get pdf filename, i have no difficulties to read pdf onAcitivtyResult.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43018/discussion-between-insomniac-and-agoeng-liu)

Comment: You need to goto this web page http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-file-path-of-gallery-image

Answer (score 0):

This function will get you the sdcard root :

```
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()
```

After getting the root you can create or open a folder.

to create a folder use

```
mkdir()
```

or

```
mkdirs()
```

functions.

to get all the files from that folder you can use File object.

Comment: I can not understand what are you trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example source code for file explorer in android :
https://github.com/mburman/Android-File-Explore

Its very straightforward forward code