# Open folder content with default file manager in android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-file

I am working with pdf files in my android app.
In a Alert Dialog pressing "Yes" should open the pdf file location in default file manager app.

I tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165972/android-how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-and-show-its-content-in-a-file) but it always open a chooser. Even-though it(ES File Explorer) opens with "Choose Path" dialog not the folder in the app as normal way of accessing folder.

So, is there possible to open directly the content of folder in "Default File Manager"? Or can open with chooser , from that selected app it should show the pdf file chooser when selecting the pdf file?.

Below is my try to achieve this.

```
public void openFolder(String filePath)
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf("/")));
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");//tried with application/pdf and file/*
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> apps = 
        pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (apps.size() > 0)
    startActivity(intent);//Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"
    }
```

**Edited**
 And I tried with ACTION_PICK too. Its directed to specific folder of default file manager.But from there selecting a file not open the chooser (pdf viewer list dialog).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to open a specific folder via Intent and show its content in a file browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165972/android-how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-and-show-its-content-in-a-file)

Comment: @LaurentY Yes agree. I resolved using the link you specified before  you comment. Forgot to update here. Thanks

Comment: Pls share your working solution coz I have got similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50072638/fileuriexposedexception-in-android/50073284?noredirect=1#comment87163542_50073284 Thank you!