# Java android pick a photo from gallery for a folder

Tags: java, android, android-gallery, android-photos, android-intent-chooser

I don't know how I can pick a photo from gallery from one folder :

Now I have this :

```
   private void galleryIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
}
```

But now I can choose a photo from all gallery and I wanto to pick a photo from a folder Test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate some sort of picker into your own app, such as perhaps [one of these file/directory chooser libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35), and remove `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
private void galleryIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        //Write your path here
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory().getPath().toString());
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider checking this answer. Looks promising. But does not work if you have no file manager installed it seems.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17173655/1987045