# How to open specific folder in google photos programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery, google-photos

I am using following code to open google photos or any gallery app

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Google Photos app create albums for folders having videos & images

My app saves videos & images in particular folder in external memory. I scan new saved video & image using media service but then I need to open that album or folder for example ExternalStorage/MyAppMedia
How can I do this? thanks

Comment: I think this link may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26651827/3820017

Comment: I tried more than that it doesn't work. thanks for sharing your thoughts