# Open specific folder using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open specific path folder using Intent, I used code for File explorer and It working perfectly but in some device (samsung devices) if file explorer app are not available then It not opening folder of specific path.
I tried many solutions but It won't work for me.

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(new File(filePath).getParent()));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder");


        if (intent.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0) != null)
        {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {

           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           intent.setDataAndType(uri, "file/*");
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));

        }
```

Comment: Try this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165972/android-how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-and-show-its-content-in-a-file

Comment: I tried that but It also opens file manager but not jumping to specific folder

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @FarooqArshed Not yet

Answer (score 2):

```
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.setDataAndType(
            Uri.parse(
                (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path
                        + java.io.File.separator) + "myFile" + java.io.File.separator
            ), "*/*"
        )
        intent.addFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    and Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                    and Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
                    and Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
        )
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_ACCESS_CODE)
```

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory()` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for accessing "root/Downloads/Sam" in **Kotlin**

```
val rootPath = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:"
val samPath = Uri.parse("$rootPath${Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS}%2fSam")    //"%2f" represents "/"

val REQUEST_CODE_PICK_FILE = 1

main_sam_button.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)                                  

    intent.type = "text/plain"    //specify file type
    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, samPath)    //set the default folder

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_FILE)
}
```

Demo:
https://youtu.be/lUIPyC_8q_M

---

Helpful reading:

- "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:":
  [What is com.android.externalstorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005727/what-is-com-android-externalstorage)

Comment: Among all the solution available on internet this solution works for me.  Yes the rootpath navigating me to internal storage. Tested Android 11.