# What is com.android.externalstorage?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-file

Despite this being a simple question I cannot find the answer on [google](https://www.google.com/search?ei=jtAuW9CtIsGZjwSh-YEI&q=what+is+com.android.externalstorage) or [stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Zv7.png).

When I use the following code I get this result `//com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:Podcasts`

```
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree);
intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true);
intent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true);
```

Can you help me understand the parts of my result?

Comment: What do you mean get the result?  There's no result there, you created an intent and done nothing with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How Android Storage works?**

To ensure security between Android apps, Android didn't let you directly access every file within the storage system. They have something called `ContentProvider`.

Think of this content provider like a waiter, that your apps can ask for a certain file/folder (through Content Uri).

Content Uri will look like this: `content://[Authority]/[path]/[id]` is just an example of Content Uri. `com.android.externalstorage.documents` is an example of authority (for access to External Storage providers).

So in your case, your Uri will gain you access to the directory of Podcasts in your External Storage.

By having Uri, you can communicate between apps or service provider easily without having to pass real file every time you ask or give one. Just pass a lightweight simple Uri.

**What happened in your code?**

If you're wondering what happens in your code, try to look at the [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).

It says:

> Allow the user to pick a directory subtree. When invoked, the system will display the various `DocumentsProvider` instances installed on the device, letting the user navigate through them. Apps can fully manage documents within the returned directory.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve (please clarify if you can, so I can help out), but I hope my answer contains enough information.