# Browse a specific folder on android

Tags: android

I'd like to know if there is a way to browse a specific folder on android, In my app folder I have a folder that contains text file I would like the user to be able to select one of them, but currently the browser will always start at the root folder of the device, not at the specified relatif location:

```
<input type='file' accept='*.txt' onchange='openFile(event)' onclick='this.value=null' src='/Sentences'><br>
```

Comment: I think the answers of this question is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165972/android-how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-and-show-its-content-in-a-file