# How to open a folder create within application in android

Tags: android, file, directory

I am generated a folder name "tesApplication" and create a file name "testFile.csc" in it and store some date into that file. Now I want to open folder dir using new intent.
I had try below code but did not work in my case any other way to achieve this.

```
Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(fileNameString);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "text/csv");

    if (intent.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0) != null)
    {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        // if you reach this place, it means there is no any file
        // explorer app installed on your device
    }
```

Comment: It is impossible what you want. Android does not provide this option.

Answer (score 0):

> ***copy this in else***

```
public void openFolder()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/myFolder/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

Comment: Its opening recent folder

Comment: You want to specify to open the folder Create ?

Comment: try change /myFolder/  to the folder you want to get to open

Comment: refer here and try : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165972/android-how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-and-show-its-content-in-a-file