# How to simply open directory/folder?

Tags: android

DONT mark this as duplicate, before reading what I need.

I have seen many similar topics, but in none of them I've found solution.
I need the simplest thing:  In my application I have button "View Media Files". After clicking that button, i need to be opened (with built-in File Explorer) this directory - **SD_CARD/my_folder** where are media files (and I want to click any of them and they should be opened in default Media player)..

I have used all suggested answers on SO , like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri mydir = Uri.parse("/sdcard/Recorder_Videos");
    intent.setDataAndType(mydir, "*/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

but all they do:   after clicking button, it opens "Choose File" menu:
(Where I cant still play media files when clicking)

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165972/android-how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-and-show-its-content-in-a-file did you check this ?

Comment: to remove the chooser remove the `Intent.createChooser` from the code

Comment: there is no must for a default file explorer on the device. It is totally optional.

Comment: `Uri.parse(location);` ??? What is the value of `location` ? How can you complain that it chooses root if we cannot even see which path you want!? `(with built-in File Explorer) ` ??? What would that be?

Comment: You show the file selection intent opening, so what's the problem?

Comment: @cricket_007 , guys, before answering, please understand the question. I have clearly described what is problem.

Comment: I didn't answer. I commented to clarify where the problem existed

Comment: Did you find any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution (not complete) I have found, was that I was missing `file://` prefix. Here is my solution (however, it shows all kinds of applications on first view):

```
public void openFolder(String location)
{
    // location = "/sdcard/my_folder";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri mydir = Uri.parse("file://"+location);
    intent.setDataAndType(mydir,"application/*");    // or use */*
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

p.s. Strange and surprising, but there doesnt exist the standard definition of "File Browser" in stock Android systems (unless you install 3rd party "File Explorer")..
That's why **`"resource/folder"`** mime-type doesnt work by default..

However, let's say a simple truth. File-Browser is a SIMPLE and ESSENTIAL part of any OS system. And it's quite disrespectful from Android, saying that it's not their job, and throwing the responsiblity to 3rd party apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type `DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR` which works on several devices and launches File Explorer. You can refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50072638/fileuriexposedexception-in-android/50102119#50102119) for more details.